# using slideup instead of dialog.open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am planning to add slideup jquery function instead of dialog.open

At the time of session timeout, user gets warning message that he will be logged off after .. seconds.

So there is javascript function

```
        onIdle: function(){
            dialog.dialog("open");
        },
```

This function opens dialog and prints text written in div tag

```
    <div id='dialog'>
```

....

Now I want to show this message in page slide up and not in dialog box.
I tried few slide up example but can't get the syntax to fire slideup event from onIdle function. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

From [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated)

```
 $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "slide",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });
```

Comment: This  slides the dialog but it is still a dialog box. This will block the page behind. Is there any way we can use jquery functions slideUp,slideDown etc.

Comment: in that case you don't need a dialog but just a div initially displayed none and when you want show it with $('#yourDiv').show('slide',funcion(){});